# Find entity by id column, \Phalcon\Mvc\Model::findFirst() gives incorrect result

Tags: php, model, phalcon

Currently i have table with posts, each posts has an id.

For a moment, only one posts exists, with id id = 92.

if i execute following code, i will get not false, but post with id=92:

```
$post = NewsPost::findFirst(['id' => 1]);
var_dump($post->id); // gives 92
```

Seems to be very strange logic.. 
What method could be used to retrieve post by id, and that will return false/throw exception if there is no such entity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$post = NewsPost::findFirst("id = 1");
```

or

```
$post = NewsPost::find(
    array(
        "conditions" => "id = ?0",
        "bind"       => array(0 => 1)
    )
);
```

Comment: Btw, if i define NewsPost::findFirst("id = 1"), will id value be escaped properly by framework?

Comment: @true Yes because the Model gets translated to PHQL which always gets escaped. However I personally prefer the second option with the bound parameters. It might be an overkill since both do the same but from a visual perspective I know that I bind my parameters thus correctly sanitize and escape them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, agree with you, second way seems more clear :)

Answer (score 5):

I use:

```
$instance = Model::findFirst($id);
```

Where $id is a primary key.

Comment: I've already checked the correct answer a long time ago, but your answer is correct (and best one). I've used to use it too.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
NewsPost::findFirst(['id = 1']);
```

or

```
NewsPost::findFirst(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
NewsPost::findByid(1);
```

Where 'id' can be replaced by any of your model's properties.  For example:

```
NewsPost::findByDescription('Description');
NewsPost::findByyourprop(yourpropval);
```

You can then count() the return value `count($result)` to determine if you received any records.

Note: I have also found the string searches to be case in-sensitive.